# Create A Twitter Login Application

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

In the past few weeks I've been developing a custom PHP login class that I will share with the rest of the devs in just a matter of days or weeks, depending on how quick I'll move with what I'm about to ask next.

So my question would be, how would I make an Twitter login for my existing login app ?

As more info, I'm using a database to store the username, the hash of the password ( a complex algorithm I've been working on most of the time does that, so it's pretty secure for now ), and the email address, also some other info that it's not relevant in here.

That is why I ask, because I've seen some examples and tutorials on how this would work but none use a database. The thing is I need somehow to have the credentials stored in the same database ( with the new columns added as necessary ) and when the user want's to login, the credentials would just be checked against the db instead of going to twitter again.

Also, only if the user is registered in my database, he could sign in with twitter, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Anyway, the main question is how would I create a Twitter login and use the database in the same time ?

Comment: Are you trying to store the users Twitter account password and username?

Comment: No, as I've read in some other questions here on Stackoverflow, I cannot actually store a username and a password, but instead other credentials to help check the login in future sign in requests. So I'm wondering what should I store in the database and how would I check it next time the user tries to login ?

Comment: Then I think @Kristen Jones answer below is what you're looking for

Comment: @Paul indeed, most of my questions have been answered by #Kristen Jones :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter used to use basic authentication, but now uses OAuth, so you wouldn't be passing the password but having the user authorize your application via Twitter's OAuth page.  There are [several](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/) [tutorials](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/) and [libraries](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) out in the world to help you do this, or you can read Twitter's [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) on implementing sign-in with Twitter.

What you'll store in your database after authenticating is the user's OAuth credentials (oauth token and secret) for future requests.

Comment: Yes, I've read that before in the same tutorials as you provided. But only those things need to be stored ? And how would I check the credentials next time against the db without being redirected to twitter ? Also is there a way to login with twitter only if you have registered on my app before you want to login with twitter ?

Comment: OAuth handles all of the login pieces for you.  Once you have the token and secret you can use those (using a PHP Oauth library) to subsequent calls with those credentials.  I'm sure there must be some sample Twitter code with examples, but if you go through the examples in the LinkedIn Getting Started guide you'll see PHP code using those credentials to make OAuth calls: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide